# Why does lxml have different behaviour compared to bs4 with lxml backend when parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, urlencode

Given this simple URL: `<a href="google.com?q=åß∂"></a>`

When parsed with lxml, the url is quoted.

However with BeautifulSoup, its unchanged.

BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print BeautifulSoup(u'<a href="google.com?q=åß∂"></a>', 'lxml')

<html><body><a href="google.com?q=åß∂"></a></body></html>
```

LXML

```
import lxml

print lxml.html.tostring(lxml.etree.fromstring(u'<a href="google.com?q=åß∂"></a>'))

<a href="google.com?q=%C3%A5%C3%9F%E2%88%82"></a>
```

Whats the reason for this difference?

Comment: That's not dependent on `lxml` parser, but how BeautifulSoup handles HTML. `BeautifulSoup(u'<a href="google.com/q=åß∂"></a>', 'html.parser')` prints also `<a href="google.com/q=åß∂"></a>`

Comment: The original search query string (`åß∂`) is percent-encoded. Is that what you mean by "quoted"?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yea so Im looking for some insight on why bs4 handles it differentially. And what purpose does lxml have if bs4 does its own thing when parsing

Comment: @mzjn Yeah, url encoding is called url quoting. At Least in python

Comment: @Krimson The parsers according the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) vary in speed, but whats really different is how they each handle invalid markup and whitespaces. For example `html5lib` tries to mimic real web browsers. You can run `bs4.diagnose` on your markup to see results with different parsers side by side.

Comment: @AndrejKesely you're correct but in this case, both my parsers are lxml. Also didnt know about bs4.diagnose. Thanks for pointing that out